C++ No such file or directory for 'splashkit.h' header file
I've been trying to fix some build issues with one of my programs, and seem to have encountered an error in relation to building my program using a header file.
Whenever I attempt to include 'splashkit.h' it says that the file is "splashkit.h: No such file or directorygcc".
The directory for this file is C:\msys64\mingw64\include\splashkit
#include "string"
#include "splashkit.h"

using namespace std;
using std::stoi;
using std::to_string;

struct Review {
    string description;
    int rating;
};

struct Movie {
    string name;
    string genre;
    string description;
    Review reviews[100];
    int review_count;
};

// Database struct
struct Database {
    Movie movies[100]; // Array to hold movies, assuming max 100 movies
    string genres[100]; // Array to hold genres, assuming max 100 genres
    int ratings[100];
    int movie_count;
    int genre_count;
    int rating_count;
};

int read_integer(const string& prompt) {
    write(prompt);
    return stoi(read_line());
}

void add_movie(Database &db);
void view_all_movies(Database &db);
void view_details(Database &db, int movie_index);
void alter_movie(Database &db, int movie_index);
void add_review(Database &db, int movie_index);
void delete_movie(Database &db, int movie_index);
void list_movies_with_genre(Database &db);
void list_all_movies_above_desired_rating(Database &db);
void main_menu(Database &db);
void details_menu(Database &db, int movie_index);

// Function to add a new movie to the database
void add_movie(Database &db) {
    Movie new_movie;

    // Get user input for movie details
    write_line("Adding a New Movie:");
    write_line("Enter the name of the movie:");
    new_movie.name = read_line();

    write_line("Select the genre of the movie:");
    write_line("1. Action");
    write_line("2. Romance");
    write_line("3. Sci-Fi");
    write_line("4. Fantasy");
    int genre_choice;
    do {
        write_line("Enter your choice (1-4):");
        genre_choice = stoi(read_line());
        switch (genre_choice) {
            case 1:
                new_movie.genre = "Action";
                break;
            case 2:
                new_movie.genre = "Romance";
                break;
            case 3:
                new_movie.genre = "Sci-Fi";
                break;
            case 4:
                new_movie.genre = "Fantasy";
                break;
            default:
                write_line("Invalid choice. Please enter a number between 1 and 4.");
                break;
        }
    } while (genre_choice < 1 || genre_choice > 4);

    // Initialize description to an empty string
    new_movie.description = "";

    write_line("Enter the description of the movie:");
    new_movie.description = read_line(); // Store the description

    // Store the new movie in the database
    db.movies[db.movie_count++] = new_movie;
}

// Function to view all movies and select one for action
void view_all_movies(Database &db) {
    write_line("Movies in the Database:");
    if (db.movie_count == 0) {
        write_line("No movies found.");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < db.movie_count; ++i) {
            write_line(to_string(i + 1) + ": " + db.movies[i].name);
        }
        write_line("Enter the number of the movie you would like to select:");
        int movie_number;
        do {
            movie_number = stoi(read_line());
            if (movie_number < 1 || movie_number > db.movie_count) {
                write_line("Invalid movie number. Please enter a number between 1 and " + to_string(db.movie_count) + ":");
            }
        } while (movie_number < 1 || movie_number > db.movie_count);
        
        // Pass control to the details_menu for the selected movie
        details_menu(db, movie_number - 1);
    }
    // Return to the main menu after details_menu
    main_menu(db); // Update function call
}

void details_menu(Database &db, int movie_index) {
    Movie selected_movie = db.movies[movie_index];
    write_line("Details Menu for " + selected_movie.name + ":");
    write_line("1. View Details");
    write_line("2. Alter Movie");
    write_line("3. Add Review");
    write_line("4. Delete Movie");
    write_line("Enter your choice (1-4):");
    int choice;
    do {
        choice = stoi(read_line());
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                view_details(db, movie_index);
                break;
            case 2:
                alter_movie(db, movie_index);
                break;
            case 3:
                // Add Review
                add_review(db, movie_index);
                break;
            case 4:
                // Delete Movie
                delete_movie(db, movie_index);
                break;
            default:
                write_line("Invalid choice. Please enter a number between 1 and 4.");
                break;
        }
    } while (choice < 1 || choice > 4);
}

void main_menu(Database &db) {
    int choice = 0;
    do {
        write_line("Main Menu:");
        write_line("1. Add Movie");
        write_line("2. View All Movies");
        write_line("3. List Movies with Genre");
        write_line("4. List Movies above Desired Rating");
        write_line("5. Main Menu");
        write_line("Enter your choice (1-5): ");
        choice = stoi(read_line());
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                add_movie(db);
                break;
            case 2:
                view_all_movies(db);
                break;
            case 3:
                list_movies_with_genre(db); // Call the function to list movies with genre
                break;
            case 4:
                list_all_movies_above_desired_rating(db); // Call the function to list movies above desired rating
                break;
            case 5:
                // Main Menu (do nothing, loop will continue)
                break;
            default:
                write_line("Invalid choice. Please enter a number between 1 and 5.");
                break;
        }
    } while (choice != 5);
}

void view_details(Database &db, int movie_index) {
    Movie selected_movie = db.movies[movie_index];
    write_line("Details for " + selected_movie.name + ":");
    write_line("Genre: " + selected_movie.genre);
    write_line("Description: " + selected_movie.description);
    write_line("Reviews:");
    if (selected_movie.review_count == 0) {
        write_line("No reviews available.");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < selected_movie.review_count; ++i) {
            write_line("Review " + to_string(i + 1) + ": " + selected_movie.reviews[i].description);
            write_line("Rating: " + to_string(selected_movie.reviews[i].rating));
        }
    }
}

void alter_movie(Database &db, int movie_index) {
    Movie &selected_movie = db.movies[movie_index]; // Reference to the selected movie
    write_line("Select what you want to alter:");
    write_line("1. Name");
    write_line("2. Genre");
    write_line("3. Description");
    write_line("4. Review Description");
    write_line("5. Rating");
    write_line("Enter your choice (1-5):");
    int choice;
    do {
        choice = stoi(read_line());
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                write_line("Enter the new name:");
                selected_movie.name = read_line();
                break;
            case 2:
                write_line("Select the new genre:");
                write_line("1. Action");
                write_line("2. Romance");
                write_line("3. Sci-Fi");
                write_line("4. Fantasy");
                int genre_choice;
                do {
                    write_line("Enter your choice (1-4):");
                    genre_choice = stoi(read_line());
                    switch (genre_choice) {
                        case 1:
                            selected_movie.genre = "Action";
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            selected_movie.genre = "Romance";
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            selected_movie.genre = "Sci-Fi";
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            selected_movie.genre = "Fantasy";
                            break;
                        default:
                            write_line("Invalid choice. Please enter a number between 1 and 4.");
                            break;
                    }
                } while (genre_choice < 1 || genre_choice > 4);
                break;
            case 3:
                write_line("Enter the new description:");
                selected_movie.description = read_line();
                break;
            case 4:
                if (selected_movie.review_count == 0) {
                    write_line("No reviews available to alter.");
                } else {
                    write_line("Select the review to alter:");
                    for (int i = 0; i < selected_movie.review_count; ++i) {
                        write_line(to_string(i + 1) + ". " + selected_movie.reviews[i].description);
                    }
                    int review_choice;
                    do {
                        write_line("Enter your choice (1-" + to_string(selected_movie.review_count) + "):");
                        review_choice = stoi(read_line());
                        if (review_choice < 1 || review_choice > selected_movie.review_count) {
                            write_line("Invalid choice. Please enter a number between 1 and " + to_string(selected_movie.review_count) + ".");
                        }
                    } while (review_choice < 1 || review_choice > selected_movie.review_count);
                    write_line("Enter the new review description:");
                    selected_movie.reviews[review_choice - 1].description = read_line();
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                if (selected_movie.review_count == 0) {
                    write_line("No reviews available to alter.");
                } else {
                    write_line("Select the review to alter:");
                    for (int i = 0; i < selected_movie.review_count; ++i) {
                        write_line(to_string(i + 1) + ". " + selected_movie.reviews[i].description);
                    }
                    int review_choice;
                    do {
                        write_line("Enter your choice (1-" + to_string(selected_movie.review_count) + "):");
                        review_choice = stoi(read_line());
                        if (review_choice < 1 || review_choice > selected_movie.review_count) {
                            write_line("Invalid choice. Please enter a number between 1 and " + to_string(selected_movie.review_count) + ".");
                        }
                    } while (review_choice < 1 || review_choice > selected_movie.review_count);
                    write_line("Enter the new rating:");
                    selected_movie.reviews[review_choice - 1].rating = stoi(read_line());
                }
                break;
            default:
                write_line("Invalid choice. Please enter a number between 1 and 5.");
                break;
        }
    } while (choice < 1 || choice > 5);
}

void add_review(Database &db, int movie_index) {
    Movie &selected_movie = db.movies[movie_index]; // Reference to the selected movie
    if (selected_movie.review_count >= 10) {
        write_line("Sorry, you can't add more than 10 reviews for a movie.");
        return;
    }
    write_line("Write a description about how you felt about the movie:");
    string review_description = read_line();
    write_line("Rate the movie from 1 to 10:");
    int rating;
    do {
        rating = stoi(read_line());
        if (rating < 1 || rating > 10) {
            write_line("Invalid rating. Please enter a number between 1 and 10:");
        }
    } while (rating < 1 || rating > 10);

    // Add the review to the selected movie
    selected_movie.reviews[selected_movie.review_count].description = review_description;
    selected_movie.reviews[selected_movie.review_count].rating = rating;
    selected_movie.review_count++;

    write_line("Review added successfully!");
}

void delete_movie(Database &db, int movie_index) {
    Movie &selected_movie = db.movies[movie_index]; // Reference to the selected movie

    // Shift movies to the left to fill the gap caused by deletion
    for (int i = movie_index; i < db.movie_count - 1; ++i) {
        db.movies[i] = db.movies[i + 1];
    }

    // Decrease the movie count to reflect the deletion
    db.movie_count--;

    write_line("Movie '" + selected_movie.name + "' deleted successfully.");
}

void list_movies_with_genre(Database &db) {
    write_line("Select the genre of movies you would like to see:");
    write_line("1. Action");
    write_line("2. Romance");
    write_line("3. Sci-Fi");
    write_line("4. Fantasy");
    
    int genre_choice;
    do {
        write_line("Enter your choice (1-4):");
        genre_choice = stoi(read_line());
        if (genre_choice < 1 || genre_choice > 4) {
            write_line("Invalid choice. Please enter a number between 1 and 4.");
        }
    } while (genre_choice < 1 || genre_choice > 4);

    string selected_genre;
    switch (genre_choice) {
        case 1:
            selected_genre = "Action";
            break;
        case 2:
            selected_genre = "Romance";
            break;
        case 3:
            selected_genre = "Sci-Fi";
            break;
        case 4:
            selected_genre = "Fantasy";
            break;
    }

    bool found = false;
    write_line("Movies with Genre '" + selected_genre + "':");
    for (int i = 0; i < db.movie_count; ++i) {
        if (db.movies[i].genre == selected_genre) {
            write_line(db.movies[i].name);
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        write_line("No movies found with genre '" + selected_genre + "'.");
    }
}

void list_all_movies_above_desired_rating(Database &db) {
    write_line("Enter the desired rating (1-10):");
    int desired_rating;
    do {
        desired_rating = stoi(read_line());
        if (desired_rating < 1 || desired_rating > 10) {
            write_line("Invalid rating. Please enter a number between 1 and 10:");
        }
    } while (desired_rating < 1 || desired_rating > 10);

    bool found = false;
    write_line("Movies with Rating Above or Equal to " + to_string(desired_rating) + ":");
    for (int i = 0; i < db.movie_count; ++i) {
        bool rating_above_desired = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < db.movies[i].review_count; ++j) {
            if (db.movies[i].reviews[j].rating >= desired_rating) {
                rating_above_desired = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (rating_above_desired) {
            write_line(db.movies[i].name);
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        write_line("No movies found with a rating above or equal to " + to_string(desired_rating) + ".");
    }
}

int main() {
    Database db; // Create the database object
    main_menu(db); // Call the main menu function with the database object
    return 0;
}


I've tried including this file directory both within the c_cpp_properties.json file and also in the settings for VSCODE, adding the file directory to the 'compiler path' items. Still not working

How are you building the code? c_cpp_properties.json is unrelated to compilation

'settings for VSCODE' is unclear. VSCode has a lot of settings. Anyway either of these is unlikely to be correct, c_cpp_properties.json has nothing to do with compilation (as already mentioned). The file you probably need to edit is tasks.json, but this does depend on which plugins you are using.

As you point out, the file is in this path: C:\msys64\mingw64\include\splashkit\splashkit.h
I assume, that you build the code using msys, so C:\msys64\mingw64\include\ is in the default include path of your compiler.
The compiler will only search for files on several pre-known paths. Those are the directory of the current code file and all of the include paths. Include paths may also be added to the compiler command (google for the usage of the argument for the compiler you use, e.g. -Ifor gcc).
So in your case, you need either include splashkit\splashkit.h instead of splashkit.h or add the C:\msys64\mingw64\include\splashkit\ path to the include paths.
#include <splashkit\splashkit.h>


Assuming that I want to include the splashkit header in the include paths, How would I go about doing that? I've tried going into the c++ include paths section and adding that directory, but it still hasnt changed anything
